# Doubling every item in list while limiting cons calls in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I have a function that doubles every item in a list:

```
(defun double (L)
   (cond
      ((atom L) nil)
      (t (cons (car L) (cons (car L ) (double (cdr L))))) ) )

(double '(a b c )) => (a a b b c c)
```

How could I accomplish the same result while dividing by 2 the number of times the function calls `cons` ? (i.e. in the previous example, it calls `cons` 6 times. How could I do it with 3 times only?)

Thanks!

Edit 2, after jkiiski's comments, seems like it works now:

```
(defun double2 (L)
   (cond
      ((atom L) nil)
      (t (setf
             (cdr L)
             (cons (car L ) (double2 (cdr L))))
         L) ) )


(double2 (list 'a 'b 'c)) => (a a b b c c)
```

Comment: A single call to `CONS` constructs one cons cell. The input has three cons cells, so clearly the only way to get a result with six cells while creating only three new ones is to reuse the old three. Notice however that in your example you're calling the function with a quoted list. Quoted lists are literal data that should not be mutated. You must call the function with a freshly constructed list -- `(double (list 'a 'b 'c))` -- if it mutates the input.

Comment: @jkiiski : thanks. So how could I "reuse" the cons already there? With rplacd?

Comment: `RPLACD` works, although most people prefer `(setf (cdr ...) ...)`.

Comment: @jkiiski : I've tried that (cf edit), but it doesn't double every item. Any idea why?

Comment: You need to return the old input that you modified.

Comment: @jkiiski : I don't see how I could do that :(

Comment: Return `L` after the `(setf ...)`. There can be multiple body forms in the `COND`-clauses.

Comment: You might want to provide a self-answer and accept it.

Comment: Doing this doesn't make your code run faster, but restrict you from using literals and otherwise mutates the input such that you need to be careful not to introduce bugs because of this premature optimization. I would rather do `(loop :for e :in l :collect e :and :collect e) ` which cons 6 times but doesn't grow the stack.

Comment: Is it homework?

Comment: @coredump: yes it is

Comment: some people prefer [RPLACD](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_rplaca.htm). it  returns the cons cell being modified, so you wouldn't need to return `L` as you had to do - with `(RPLACD L ...)` it'd just work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After jkiiski's comments, seems like it works now:

```
(defun double2 (L)
   (cond
      ((atom L) nil)
      (t (setf
             (cdr L)
             (cons (car L ) (double2 (cdr L))))
         L) ) )

(double2 (list 'a 'b 'c)) => (a a b b c c)
```

Comment: best not to use dangling parentheses alone on their line.

Answer (score 2):

Here is an another way of doing it, without recursion. Note that this answer assumes you are doing a homework and trying to find a way to avoid creating a fresh list, which is what the simplest solution does. In practice, you would simply use `collect` twice in a `loop`, like Sylwester demonstrated. Here the original input list is destructively modified.

#### Copy list

Suppose your original `list` is `(1 2 3)`.  Instead of consing
elements yourself, you can call `(copy-list list)`, which performs the
required amount of consing. That's all you need to consider for memory
allocation. Then, you "only" need to interleave all the cons cells to
obtain the desired repetition.

Keep the `list` variable as given, and define two variables which
iterate over both lists:

```
current = (1 2 3) ;; original
  fresh = (1 2 3) ;; copy
```

#### Reordering cells

Graphically, you want to change CDRs to "thread" existing cons-cells together. At first, both lists look like this:

```
  current   ( 1 . x-)-->( 2 . x-)-->...

  fresh     ( 1 . x-)-->( 2 . x-)-->...
```

But you want to have:

```
  current   ( 1 . x )   ( 2 . x )
                  |     ^     |
                  V     |     V
  fresh           ( 1 . x )   ( 2 . ...)
```

More formally, at the beginning of each step, and when your lists are not empty, the above variables can be decomposed as follows:

```
current = (chead . ctail)
  fresh = (fhead . ftail)
```

You want to make `current`'s tail point to the `fresh` cons-cell, and make `fresh`'s tail point to `ctail`.
Once you finish interleaving cells, the variables should be bound as follows:

```
current = (chead . (fhead . ctail))
  fresh = ftail
```

And then, you can descend twice in `current`, so that finally:

```
current = ctail
  fresh = ftail
```

From here, you can continue with the rest of both lists. Note that
`list` still contains the original cons cell you were given as an
input.

#### Code

```
(defun double-loop (list)
  (loop
    with fresh = (copy-list list)                 ;; cursor to new cons cells
    with current = list                           ;; cursor to current cell
    while fresh                                   ;; stop when fresh is nil
    do (print (list list current fresh))          ;; for debugging
       (rotatef (cdr fresh) (cdr current) fresh)  ;; change CDRs, rebind fresh
       (setf current (cddr current))              ;; update CURRENT
    finally (return list)))                       ;; LIST points to head of result
```

I am using [`ROTATEF`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm) to wire cons cells:

```
(rotatef (cdr fresh) (cdr current) fresh)
```

What happens is that the value of `fresh` is placed in `(cdr current)`, whose previous value is itself placed in `(cdr fresh)`, the original
value of which eventually becomes the new value bound to `fresh`.

#### Example

Here is an example trace output:

```
CL-USER> (double-loop (list 0 1 2 3))

((0 1 2 3) (0 1 2 3) (0 1 2 3)) 
((0 0 1 2 3) (1 2 3) (1 2 3)) 
((0 0 1 1 2 3) (2 3) (2 3)) 
((0 0 1 1 2 2 3) (3) (3))

=> (0 0 1 1 2 2 3 3)
```

Comment: This calls `cons` 6 times too, just under the hood.

Comment: @Sylwester (1) It might be homework and it is not useless to learn at least once how to manipulate cons-cells, or when ROTATEF can be used (2) when you are saying 6, you probably count the original list creation, which is not what the question is about (if, instead of printing intermediate results, I collect them, I finally obtain `((#1=(1 . #2=(1 . #3=(2 . #4=(2 . #5=(3 . #6=(3)))))) #1# #2#) (#1# #3# #4#) (#1# #5# #6#) (#1# NIL NIL))`.  (3) That being said, I agree 100% that this not the kind of code that should be encouraged to do. I'll add a remark about that.

Comment: Thanks. I get the general idea, although I don't grasp all the details of the code at the end. Will have a close look and play around with it.

Comment: You might want to first eval `(setf *print-circle* t)` to avoid infinite loop when printing circular structure (this may happen if you set the cdr of a cons-cell to one that (in)directly references that cell), see http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw51/CLHS/Body/v_pr_cir.htm